# How to plot PCA with paired data?

Tags: pca

I am currently working with genetic data from different patients. To date I have always worked with PCAs by comparing independent groups. Example: (Sick Vs Control, Treatment Vs Control etc.)

But now I have paired data. I mean that there exists a relationship between the samples of different groups. The typical example is having a group of subjects and measuring each of them before and after treatment.

[image]

I did this PCA with Thermofisher program, but I would like to do in R. This is the output of the ThermoFisher program. B (Before treatment) P (Post-treatment)

[image]

I tried to looking for any example in Google, but I didn't found it.

An example would be something like this:

```
data.matrix <- matrix(nrow=100, ncol=10)
colnames(data.matrix) <- c(
  paste("P_BT", 1:5, sep=""),
  paste("P_AT", 1:5, sep=""))
rownames(data.matrix) <- paste("gene", 1:100, sep="")
for (i in 1:100) {
  wt.values <- rpois(5, lambda=sample(x=10:1000, size=1))
  ko.values <- rpois(5, lambda=sample(x=10:1000, size=1))

  data.matrix[i,] <- c(wt.values, ko.values)
}
head(data.matrix)
```

Comment: What is the aim of the PCA? Is it to compare the two groups on a lower dimensional space?

Comment: @MichaelM Yes. I have more 100 patients with more than 40000 genes. Basically my team took a blood sample from 90 patients before treatment and after treatment. So what I want to have, it's a difference between the two groups.

Comment: sounds more like SVM than PCA, but you might lower the dimensions first before doing the SVM

Comment: if you want to describe the space of the two groups, use SVM.
if you just want to have a nice diagram, take the first 2 or 3 principal components from the PCA.

Comment: @draz yes, but how? I mean, how can I take into account each patient's information?

Comment: the difference per patient is a vector from BEFORE to AFTER. maybe you want to do a PCA on these difference-vectors?

Comment: @draz yes, that is what I want, but I don't know how to say to R that must have into account those groups

Comment: then its probably more an R-question (which I never used so far)

Comment: most likely you need to regress out the effects of individuals, and do a PCA on this individuals